# Kafka sink connector not committing offsets but consuming messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, snowflake-connector

I am using kafka-connector to sink messages to snowflake.
Docker image: `cp-kafka-connect-base:6.2.0`

I have two consumer pods running in distributed mode. Please find the connect-config below

```
  connector.class: "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector"
  tasks.max: "2"
  topics: "test-topic"
  snowflake.topic2table.map: "test-topic:table1"
  buffer.count.records: "500000"
  buffer.flush.time: "240"
  buffer.size.bytes: "100000000"
  snowflake.url.name: "<url>"
  snowflake.warehouse.name: "name"
  snowflake.user.name: "username"
  snowflake.private.key: "key"
  snowflake.private.key.passphrase: "pass"
  snowflake.database.name: "db-name"
  snowflake.schema.name: "schema-name"
  key.converter: "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter"
  value.converter: "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter"
```

envs:

```
  CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "testgroup" 
  CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: "snowflakesync-config"
  CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: "snowflakesync-status"
  CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: "snowflakesync-offset"
  CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "localhost"
  CONNECT_REST_PORT: "8083"
  CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "3"
  CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: "5000"
  CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "3"
  CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "3"
  CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
  CONNECTOR_NAME: "test-conn"
```

I am running two pods with the above config. Two pods are properly attached to one partition each and starts consuming.

Question ::
Whenever I deploy / restart the pods,the offets are getting committed [ CURRENT-OFFSET is getting updated] **only ONCE** , post that the **sink connector keeps consuming the messages from topic, but the current-offset is NOT at all updated**. ( offsets are not getting committed )

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <server>  --describe --group connect-test-conn
```

This is the command used to check the Current-offset is getting updated or not. Since only once the current_offset is updated, it always shows a lag and the lag keeps increasing.

But , I could see in logs ( put records ) & from snowflake the events are getting persisted.

Would like to know why the offsets are not getting committed continuously.

Example case: ( output of consumer-group command )

```
TOPIC                 PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                                HOST            CLIENT-ID
events-sync            0          6408022         25524319        19116297        connector-consumer-events-sync-0-b9142c5f-3bb7-47b1-bd44-a169a7984952 /xx.xx.xx.xx   connector-consumer-events-sync-0
events-sync            1          25521059        25521202        143                 connector-consumer-events-sync-1-107f2aa8-969c-4d7e-87f8-fdb2be2480b3 /xx.xx.xx.xx    connector-consumer-events-sync-1
```

Comment: This connector seems to use a buffer, and I assume that the offsets are only committed when the buffer is cleared, such as when the connector is restarted, otherwise you need to wait `buffer.flush.time`

Comment: thanks @OneCricketeer , sorry for the late follow up. buffer.flush.time - No. of seconds between buffer flushes, where the flush is from the Kafka’s memory cache to the internal stage( snowflake ) .

Comment: In this case, I could further observe only one of the sink connect client nodes is not committing ( sometimes both ) .. added a sample at the last in description.